# Why is `exp && "t" || "f"` much slower than inline-if-else?

Tags: javascript, performance, jsperf

Why is the *logical expressio*n twice slower than *if-else* or *inline-if-else*?

```
function logicalExp(val) {
  return val && "t" || "f";
}

function inlineIfElse(val) {
  return val ? "t" : "f";
}    

function ifElse(val) {
  if (val) return "t";
  else return "f";
}
```

- All functions evaluate with same results.
- All functions are being passed a value from an array of `1` and `0`, see this [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/ifelseexp).

Comment: As per my understanding `val && "t" || "f"` and `val ? "t" : "f"` are not same

Comment: @Satpal Then paste those two snippets into your browser console, replace `val` by `true` or `false` and see.

Comment: Nothing says that val is a boolean

Comment: The third one could likely be sped up more if you remove the `else` (but leave the return statement).

Comment: @yunandtidus I never said that, but it will be evaluated as a boolean (both by `&&` and `?:`), so any other value will be *treated* as if it was `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'm guessing the last two expressions are a clear cut true or false evaluation, whereas the first one has far more inner workings to evaluate the expression and return the value. This would result in a slow down.

Comment: I'm confused. This question is: why is performing two evaluations `val` and `t` slower than just evaluating `val`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy: [Not really](http://jsperf.com/ifelseexp/2). They're semantically equivalent, and should compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: @Marc The question really is why `() && _ || _` is 2x slower than `() ? _ : _`, it's not about the values, it's the principle.

Comment: @Bergi Interesting. I find it odd that the `if-else` and `if-return` statements were exactly the same.

Comment: @Qwerty  `x && y || z` evaluates the truthyness of `x`, and then the truthyness of `y`. There are *two* tests. `x ? y : z` evaluates the truthyness of `x` *only*, just *one* test. I would absolutely expect `?:` to be twice as fast as `&& ||` because it's doing *half* the comparisons.

Comment: @meagar lol, I see what I did there now. So simple. Make it into an answer, please.

Comment: @Qwerty Bergi's answer says the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it does need to evaluate whether `"t"` is truthy or not. The [short-circuit expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) `return ((val && "t") || "f")` can be expanded to

```
var and = val ? "t" : val;
var or = and ? and : "f";
return or;
```

Of course, an optimising compiler could statically determine the truthiness of the `"t"` literal, and avoid doing `ToBoolean(val)` twice, but apparently this is not done in any JS engine.

Comment: @Marc: What do you mean by "*before assignment*"? And no, `val && "t"` does evaluate either to `val` or to `"t"`, it's not casted to a boolean.

Comment: @Marc Why would it do that? The returned value is `"f"`, what would the program do with the evaluated boolean? Just discard?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen this code. What is it? Seems redundant.. Do you have some references?

Comment: @Bergi, Siguza: removed my comment as to not confuse the issue. In short: I'm an idiot and what I was thinking was dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
val && "t" || "f"
```

has to evaluate `val` and, if `val` evaluates to `true`, `"t"` as well.

Using [only `false`](http://jsperf.com/ifelseexp/4) is therefore significantly faster than [only `true`](http://jsperf.com/ifelseexp/3), but still quite slow.

Comment: The “only false” and “only true” link are the same…